# Algorithms - optimal way to buy and sell a stock over an interval

Tags: algorithm, finance

Someone gave me a problem from a textbook that I can't figure out. It is:

Let's say that you have a stock STOK that you are set on investing all of your money in for a month (days `0...30`), and at the end of the month you can't hold any of the stock. You have `m` money. For any day `d` the price of STOK is `p(d)`, and on any day you can either buy or sell stock. However, there is a limit, `l(d)`, to how much stock you can buy and sell in one day (it's the same for buying and selling). You can buy non-integer units of stock if you want, for ease of calculation. Given these functions, how do you schedule a purchase plan to maximize your profit?

The naive solution: Every day buy as much stock as you can under the following constraints: If you are unable to sell all of your stock by the sell date do not buy any more; If you are out of money, do not buy any more. When you reach the point where you must begin selling stock (this is known, for you know the stock prices in advance) then sell as much as you can every day. This solution doesn't work, however, because what if the stock dips at the beginning of the month then soars after the first five days?

This smells like dynamic programming, but the fact that the stock price isn't monotone makes it hard. Brute force is clearly out given the continuous nature of the problem. Any solutions?

Comment: Continuous? Prices are stable for each day, so they are discrete. Stock is discrete. Money is discrete. None of this is continuous, unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: @G.Bach Sorry, it's assumed (but I forgot to write) that you can buy non-discrete units of stock if you want, for ease of calculations. I'll put that in now.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the stock prices in advance, this sounds a lot like a problem in recursion (brute force).  You build an array of the daily stock price, the daily limit, daily cash on hand, and daily stock owned.
Use a recursive function that accepts each of these arrays as arguments.  Pick one of the possible pairs of days that haven't been marked, mark one buy and one sell, update all of the arrays, enforcing the proper limits and  recurse, if the cash at the end of the month is greater than the starting cash, save the array set as the new max, reset the arrays to the starting point, pick the next pair of days and continue until all have been tried.